# I want to disable the save button if any of the fields have red border

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to disable the save button until all the fields are valid and not to enable if any one field border turns red. The jsp is included with more jsp's and I am finding it difficult to get the form/div into my java script function

I am triying to get the form/div id dynamically using the jquery but in the JavaScript it fails to the id of the form

```
onkeyup="checkFieldWithRegExp(jQuery('#SUM-03-inputnumberOfChildren'), jQuery('#teleNumeric'), jQuery('#FO-E012-tableShowMarketingConsent'));


function checkFieldWithRegExp(valueField, regExpField, formIdField) {
    var regExp = regExpField.val();
    var regNumber = valueField.val();
    var formIdValue = $('#formIdField input:not(.hilightBorder)').length();

    if (regExp !== null && !new RegExp(regExp).test(regNumber)) {       
        valueField.addClass('hilightBorder');
        valueField.removeClass('hilightGreenBorder')
        $('SUM00bSaveButton').disabled=false;
    } else if(regExp !== null && new RegExp(regExp).test(regNumber)){
        valueField.addClass('hilightGreenBorder');
        valueField.removeClass('hilightBorder');
        if(formIdValue){
            $('SUM00bSaveButton').disabled=false;
        }
    } else {
        valueField.removeClass('hilightBorder');
    }   
}
```

I expect to disable the save when page loads and if any of the fields have red border which user input is wrong. Can I please get some help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are approaching the problem wrong.

From my understanding of what you are trying to do, you are enabling a button once the form input is valid. (correct me if i'm wrong)

You should being writing a function in the background to check and validate the the input data that the user is filling out. If all the data is valid, then enable the button. If not valid, disable it.

You can run this function every time there is an "onKeyUp" event that is attached to each form input element.